# MyBatis update annotation failed - ORACLE ERROR ORA-00933

Tags: oracle, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

In a classic spring boot application I've this query in Mapper

```
@Update("UPDATE MY_TABLE SET STATUS_CODE=#{status} WHERE ID_DOC=#{idDoc};")
void updateStatus(@Param("status") final String status,@Param("idDoc") final BigDecimal idDoc);
```

When I execute method ORA-00933 is returned.

The query works fine in SQLPLUS

What's wrong?

Comment: Remove the `;` semi-colon from the end of the query. A `;` terminator is not valid in an SQL statement (it is needed for PL/SQL statements though).

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CNXK3GTz)